# Sql count and min

Tags: mysql

I have a question on how to do the following sql command:

Report the course(s) with lowest enrollments. You should output the course code and the number of enrollments.

The Table in question:
- A table Enrollment with CourseCode, SectionNo, StudentID, and Grade

I don't know where to begin with this so any help would be really appreciated.

I tried the following which doesn't work at all:

```
select p.CourseCode, count(p.StudentID) AS Num_Students
from Enrollment p
where count(p.StudentID) = ( select min( select count(e1.StudentID)) from Enrollment e1 where e1.CourseCode = p.CourseCode)
group by p.CourseCode;
```

The result I am trying for is to have the CourseCode and the number of students for only the courses with the min amount of StudentIDS. I think my logic is good but I don't know sql syntax well enough to get what I want.

Comment: If you want help on this website, please start by telling us : What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Get the course with minimum non-zero count of studentid (lowest number of enrollments):

```
SELECT COUNT(e.studentid) AS lowest_nonzero_count 
  FROM Enrollment e
 GROUP BY e.coursecode
 ORDER BY 1
 LIMIT 1
```

But if we want to consider courses that don't have any enrollments (i.e. if we consider that zero is a valid value for the lowest number of enrollments)

```
SELECT COUNT(e.studentid) AS lowest_count
  FROM course c
  LEFT
  JOIN enrollment e
    ON e.coursecode = c.coursecode
 GROUP BY c.coursecode
 ORDER BY 1
 LIMIT 1
```

Which courses have that lowest (non-zero) count of studentid? If we know the specific value, we could do this (representing that value with a placeholder `:lowest_nonzero_count`:

```
SELECT d.coursecode
     , COUNT(d.studentid)
  FROM enrollment d
 GROUP BY d.coursecode 
HAVING COUNT(d.studentid) = :lowest_nonzero_count
```

It's possible for us to replace the `:lowest_nonzero_count` placeholder with a subquery that returns the value:

```
SELECT d.coursecode
     , COUNT(d.studentid)
  FROM enrollment d
 GROUP BY d.coursecode 
HAVING COUNT(d.studentid) = 
       ( SELECT COUNT(e.studentid)
           FROM Enrollment e
          GROUP BY e.coursecode
          ORDER BY 1
          LIMIT 1
       )
 ORDER BY d.coursecode
```

If we want to consider a "zero" value as a valid number of enrollments:

```
SELECT b.coursecode
     , COUNT(d.studentid)
  FROM course b
  LEFT
  JOIN enrollment d
    ON d.coursecode = b.coursecode
 GROUP BY b.coursecode
HAVING COUNT(d.studentid) = 
       ( SELECT COUNT(e.studentid)
           FROM course c
           LEFT
           JOIN enrollment e
             ON e.coursecode = c.coursecode
          GROUP BY c.coursecode
          ORDER BY 1
          LIMIT 1
       )
 ORDER BY b.coursecode
```